# SG500 Boot Code Upgrade

Tags: cisco, firmware, tftp

I am trying to upgrade one of my switches it is an SG500 boot code 1.3.0.03. I have tried to tftp boot code 1.3.5 up to the switch but the tftp keeps giving me server aborted file not found. File is there.

is there a boot code before that version I am not seeing?